# Docker has crashed and has lost data

Tags: mongodb, docker

Is there any way to get the following data back? It's still on the server, but when I hit the start button on the Docker MongoDB it did not start this data

```
WiredTiger         WiredTigerLAS.wt                     collection-4-3972727367510052707.wt  index-3-3972727367510052707.wt  index-9-3972727367510052707.wt  storage.bson                  WiredTiger.lock    _mdb_catalog.wt                      collection-7-3972727367510052707.wt  index-5-3972727367510052707.wt  journal                                                       WiredTiger.turtle  collection-0-3972727367510052707.wt  diagnostic.data                      index-6-3972727367510052707.wt  mongod.lock                                                   WiredTiger.wt      collection-2-3972727367510052707.wt  index-1-3972727367510052707.wt       index-8-3972727367510052707.wt  sizeStorer.wt
```

Comment: It appears there is a helpful and fulsome answer below that probably needs your attention. It is not mandatory to reply to, vote on, or accept an answer, but it is certainly a reasonable social expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the above files not corrupted then you just to need to mount these files and directory with the container.

```
docker run --name some-mongo -v $PWD/datadir:/data/db -d mongo
```

Also, you can check `docker-initdb.log`

Then you can verify the connection.

```
docker exec -it some-mongo bash
```

Mongo DB creates some of these files by default on mount location.

```
collection-0-8843715472963721221.wt  index-9-8843715472963721221.wt
collection-2-8843715472963721221.wt  journal
collection-4-8843715472963721221.wt  _mdb_catalog.wt
collection-7-8843715472963721221.wt  mongod.lock
diagnostic.data                      sizeStorer.wt
docker-initdb.log                    storage.bson
index-1-8843715472963721221.wt       WiredTiger
index-3-8843715472963721221.wt       WiredTigerLAS.wt
index-5-8843715472963721221.wt       WiredTiger.lock
index-6-8843715472963721221.wt       WiredTiger.turtle
index-8-8843715472963721221.wt       WiredTiger.wt
```